# C# LINQ, convert a number of parallel for loops nested in a foreach

Tags: c#, linq

My goal is to master the LINQ library functions.

My question is, how can I call multiple Selects in a SelectMany iteration?

Consider the following code:

```
foreach(var i in array){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return someOtherArray[i];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return someOtherArray[i];
}
```

I know the conversion with 1 loop nested,

```
return array.SelectMany(x => 
           Enumerable.Range(0,10)
             .Select(i => someOtherArray[i]));
```

but how on earth do I run over on another separated inner for loop inside the selectMany scope?

---

**Edit #1**

I need to run over 2 arrays inside a parent array

```
foreach(var i in array) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
        yield return someOtherArray_A[i];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
        yield return someOtherArray_B[i];
}
```

---

**Edit #2**

Apologizing for changing so many inputs, I'm trying to get it closer to my real problem.

```
 foreach(var j in array) {
     for(int i=0; i<20; i++) 
         yield return someOtherArray_A[i];
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
         yield return someOtherArray_B[i];
 }
```

Comment: Did you look at `Union()` to combine the output of multiple `Select`s?

Comment: Not `Union`, but `Concat`

Comment: This entire code doesn't make any sense to me and it doesn't even compile !. What are you exactly trying to do ?

Comment: I think it'd be more useful if you gave an example of what `array`, `someOtherArray_A` and `someOtherArray_B` contained, then tell us what output you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your current code doesn't make much sense. Now, if I change your code so that it would make some sense, it could for example be like this.

```
foreach(var item in array){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return item.someArray[i];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return item.someOtherArray[i];
}
```

The inner loops are iterating over data from the outer loop.

Now how would this look when you use Linq?

```
return array.SelectMany(x =>
    x.someArray.Take(10).Concat(
        x.someOtherArray.Take(10)
    )
);
```

You can use `.SelectMany()` to combine inner sequences to one longer sequences, and you can use `.Concat()` to glue together two sequences, and use it as one.

Comment: Not quite sure how exactly  I return in each iteration a value from both arrays by using Take in your example

Comment: @USS-Montana That is a different question.

Comment: @USS-Montana You original loop doesn't even do what you're saying in your comment.

Comment: @user3185569 I'm yielding in every iteration a value from somearray_A and synchronously yielding a value from somearray_B...  (see edit)

Comment: @USS-Montana No, you are not. You are first yielding 10 values from A, after that you are yielding 10 values from B. Not 1-of-A, 1-of-B, 1-of-A, 1-of-B, etc.

Comment: @USS-Montana No, you're yielding 10 items from someOtherArray_A **one after the other** and **then** after those 10 items are done, you yield 10 items from someOtherArray_A **one after the other**.

Comment: @USS-Montana And your code still doesn't compile, since the variable `i` is defined twice. Thats why I changed the outer `i` to `item`.

Comment: Oh, I was sure I meant that by my reply... :)   (no debate then, were on the same page)

Comment: @USS-Montana Ok, can you then explain why my Linq version wouldn't work?

Comment: few seconds for implementation, be back to you asap

Comment: Concat was the solution, thanks alot @Maarten & user3185569

Comment: Not quite the same behaviour here if the array has < 10 items

Comment: @Rawling True. In that case an exception would have been thrown, which in my case isn't. Up to the OP to decide which is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Maarten's Sensible version of the code:

```
foreach(var item in array){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return item.someArray[i];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
       yield return item.someOtherArray[i];
}
```

So you want to return the first 10 elements of both (inner) arrays for every (outer) array.

So we can LINQ-ify the inner part like this:

```
    item.someArray.Take(10)                // the first 10 elements of this array
        .Concat(                           // followed by
            item.someOtherArray.Take(10)); // the first 10 elements of this array
}
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` of whatever type the inner array has.
Now we want to do this for all item in the outer array and return it as a single sequence, which is exactly what `SelectMany` does:

```
array.SelectMany(item => item.someArray.Take(10).Concat(item.SomeOtherArray.Take(10)));
```

Comment: Not quite the same behaviour here if the array has < 10 items

Comment: True, but since OP is learning about this, I would argue this version is better in a general sense.